# Why is the second div in my container not showing?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating two divs next to each other using code I found on another thread. The problem is that the first div should have a fixed value and the second should just fill the rest, but it seems like it just removes the second div when I'm trying to give it a percentage:

```css
     #wrapper {
         width: 100%;
         overflow: auto; /* so the size of the wrapper is alway the size of the longest content */
         height: 150px;
         margin-bottom: 10px;
         overflow-y:hidden;
      overflow-x:hidden;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background-color: #f1f2f4;
     }
     #first {
         float: left;
         width: 150px;
         height:150px;
     }
     #second {
      width:100%;
      height:150px;
         float:left;
     padding: 1.5em;
     }
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="first">Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it.</div>
        <div id="second">When you post a new question, other users will almost immediately see it and try to provide good answers. This often happens in a matter of minutes, so be sure to check back frequently when your question is still new for the best response.</div>
    </div>
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: try using `position` in your css . Just for hint see this `http://jsfiddle.net/nepal12/g6u9ktc9/` . See here `http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why the problem occurs:

You have `#second { width:100%; }`. This means that both elements won't fit next to each other since the second one will need the full width of the container. But the first element already takes all the height, and you have `overflow: hidden;` so the second one goes out of the container (below) and is not visible at all. Just to see where it went you can reduce the height of the first item a bit (say from 150px to 120px).

---

Your layout can very easily and intuitively be achieved with `flex-box` instead of floats. All modern browsers support it now.

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f1f2f4;
    display: flex;
}
#first {
    width: 150px;
    height:150px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
#second {
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  padding: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first">
        Lorem ipsum whatever I'm writting in here.
    </div>
    <div id="second">
        Lorem ipsum whatever I'm writting in here.
        Lorem ipsum whatever I'm writting in here.
        Lorem ipsum whatever I'm writting in here.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This may solve the problem but it doesn't explain why the problem is occurring.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks for pointing it out. I completely forgot to explain that part.

Comment: Good addition, but I think you left out a word in your second-to-last sentence before the code ("be") :-)

Comment: @TylerH You're like the police! :-) Fortunately I see you have enough privilege to edit answers. You can be my guest to edit what you think needs improvement.

Answer (score 3):

The probem is you set `width:100%` and `float`, with `100%` there is no way that div can floats aside the previous one.

- You can remove the float and width on the second one, but maybe you can't handle well the padding:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  /* so the size of the wrapper is alway the size of the longest content */
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f1f2f4;
}
#first {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
#second {
  height: 150px;
  padding: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first">Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it.</div>
  <div id="second">When you post a new question, other users will almost immediately see it and try to provide good answers. This often happens in a matter of minutes, so be sure to check back frequently when your question is still new for the best response.</div>
</div>
```

- Or use `calc` and `box-sizing` to determine the `width`:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  /* so the size of the wrapper is alway the size of the longest content */
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f1f2f4;
}
#first {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
#second {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  float:left;
  width:calc(100% - 150px);
  height: 150px;
  padding: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first">Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it.</div>
  <div id="second">When you post a new question, other users will almost immediately see it and try to provide good answers. This often happens in a matter of minutes, so be sure to check back frequently when your question is still new for the best response.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your #wrapper element has a fixed height. The #second element is off the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Since "second" spans the whole width it wraps to the next line and is hidden because the container has a fixed height. Just remove width and float attributes from "second" div.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just writing this answer to make people avoid wasting their time on debugging for just a silly mistake, like i did. Any div that i was placing next to my "navbar div" in my website was going before my navbar instead of going next to it. When i removed the "position: fixed;" in my navbar it went quite well.The problem usually occurs with my code is that sometimes i do this with my navbar:

```
 .anyclass
{
        position : fixed;
}
```